# Return key with tf.estimator model predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am using a custom tensorflow Estimator and am trying to use

```
tf.contrib.estimator.forward_features
```

to return a key column along with my outputs. I followed [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271114/define-instance-key-index-number-for-cloud-machine-learning-prediction) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542369/how-to-get-keys-in-batch-predictions-with-ml-engine-using-a-custom-model?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and applied

```
tf.contrib.estimator.forward_features
```

but I am receiving the the error

```
 Predictions should be a dict to be able to forward features. Given: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

My model functions looks like this

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    values = nnet(features)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
       is_training = True
    else:
       is_training = False

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
       predictions = {
        'class_ids': tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(values),1),
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(values),
        'logits': values,
        }
        export_outputs = {
            'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)
        }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,predictions=predictions,export_outputs=export_outputs)

    labels_one_hot=tf.one_hot(labels,4)

    score= tf.argmax(values,axis=1)

    loss_op= tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=values,labels=labels_one_hot))

    gradients = tf.gradients(loss_op, tf.trainable_variables())

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=.0001)

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

        train_optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tf.trainable_variables()),

        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

        acc_op=tf.metrics.accuracy( labels= labels,predictions=tf.argmax(values, axis=1))

        tf.summary.scalar('accuracy_rate', acc_op[1])
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

        estim_specs = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
             mode=mode,
             predictions=score,
             loss=loss_op,
             train_op=train_optimizer,
        eval_metric_ops={'acc': acc_op})
        return estim_specs 


    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        predicted_indices = tf.argmax(values, axis=1)
        eval_metric_ops = {
          'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predicted_indices)}

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,loss=loss_op,eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

I am calling my estimator like this

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn= model_fn,
    config= tf.estimator.RunConfig(
            save_checkpoints_steps = 2000,
            keep_checkpoint_max = 10,
            tf_random_seed = 101),
          model_dir= "tf_dir")

estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.forward_features(
  estimator,'key')

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I am returning a dictionary for my predictions and my code runs fine if I don't call

```
tf.contrib.estimator.forward_features
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly carry the key into model function and add it to the dictionary of outputs.

The lines of code that need to be added are

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    values = nnet(features)
```

add the key here

```
    key=features["key_column"]

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        is_training = True
    else:
        is_training = False


    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {
            'class_ids': tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(values),1),
             'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(values),
             'logits': values,
```

add the key to the dictionary outputs

```
            'key_column':key
           }
        export_outputs = {
        'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)
          }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,predictions=predictions,export_outputs=export_outputs)
```